# Efficient way of executing 2 functions one after another in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two functions

```
function one() {
    setTimeout(function(){ console.log("first function executed"); }, 3000);
}

function two() {
    console.log("second function executed");
}
```

How can i let second function waits till first function executed? What is the easiest way for a beginner? Thanx

Comment: Literally `one();two();`, but I think what you actually mean is wait for the timer callback to execute before calling `two()`, right?

Comment: Yes @spender i mean wait for the timer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could approach this, the two most common ways would be using a callback, or using Promises.

## Using Callbacks

You would add a callback argument to the first function, and then pass in function two as the callback:

```js
function one(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("first function executed");
    callback();
  }, 3000);
}

function two() {
  console.log("second function executed");
}

one(two)
```

## Using Promises:

Promises allow you to chain different actions together that are dependant on ordering. However, you may need to add polyfills to support older browsers:

```js
function one() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("first function executed");
      resolve();
    }, 3000);
  })
}

function two() {
  console.log("second function executed");
}

one().then(two)
```

Comment: There is no wait between functions one and two in this example. You could add one, but I think callbacks and promises are a little complex for beginners and are a bit over-the top and unnecessary for the simple task at hand. Not to mention that this code simply looks more confusing to beginners.

Comment: Thanx @KevBot, this is a perfect example for promise. I couldn't find anywhere so an easy example.

Comment: @Feathercrown, there is, it waits 3 seconds to console.log, and then immediately calls function `two`. And the only difference in "complexity" of yours vs mine (for callbacks) is that I formatted my code to multiple lines.

Comment: @AdamJungen, Great! I'm glad that the Promises example helped and provided more context for understanding promises.